# Unabled to deploy django + apache on aws Ubuntu server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, http-status-code-500

I am trying to deploy a Django Application using Apache on an Ubuntu Server, I am having a weird error (500 internal error server error) when using port :80.

I made some test using port :8000 running the command:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And the application is working without any problem there, but when I try to access the application using port 80 it does work.

My apache config file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


Alias /static /home/ubuntu/gh_system/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/gh_system/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/gh_system/HRSYSTEM>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess HRSYSTEM python-home=/home/ubuntu/gh_system/env python-path=/home/ubuntu/gh_system>
WSGIProcessGroup HRSYSTEM
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/gh_system/HRSYSTEM/wsgi.py
```

I reviewed the apached2 errors logs, and I am getting a: No module named 'django', my wsgi files is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "HRSYSTEM.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Have you already tried accessing the application through port 8000?

Comment: @LeoAlan Yes! and it is working fine on port 8000. I am looking the error logs of apache2 and I am getting an error: No module named 'django'; adding wsgi config to the post for more information.

Comment: Could be a version issue. I see that you are manually running it on port 8000 using python3. Do you have multiple versions of python on your unbuntu server? Check [multiple version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302698/django-mod-wsgi-apache-server-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django) or [libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330231/500-internal-server-error-mod-wsgi-apache-importerror-no-module-named-django/43354916#43354916)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, testing and reviewing the apache logs with:

```
sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I found that the problem was related to this line:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess HRSYSTEM ***python-home=/home/ubuntu/gh_system/env*** python-path=/home/ubuntu/gh_system>
```

Basically, apache was trying to read the packages inside of the virtual environment but I did install them using the command:

```
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Apparently, using the "sudo" command was installing the packages outside the virtual environment, it is so weird; but without "sudo" the console logs the error permission denied, so I give chmod 700 permission to the virtual environment and install again the packages without the "sudo", and then it works!

Some of the things I learned about the errors:

```
Problem: Not module 'encodings' --> this problem occurs when apache can not access your packages, usually for a bad path specified in the config file.

Problem: Not module 'x module, could be django' means you need to install the package using pip3.
```

Hope it helps someone! and just to point out, something I have been learning lately, is: when you spend too much time trying to solve a problem, and there is not much information about it on internet, it means that something really, really basic is failing in your project; for example, installing the packages outside the virtual environment without even realizing it, just like I did.